# ¿Qué es exactamente una "ponencia"? (academia)

Tags: hispanoamérica, lenguaje-académico

Hay un trabajo académico de mi interés cuya postulación me pide detalles de "ponencias en congresos". Este apartado se encuentra en la sección de "Publicaciones". Por ende, mi interpretación de "ponencia" es algún tipo de material académico escrito mandado a conferencias (y aceptado, lógicamente).

Pero si ese es el caso, entonces me entra la duda. Lo que no entiendo es cuál es la relevancia de este ítem. Por un lado, en mi disciplina (Economía), siempre se mandan textos escritos para conferencias, ya sea abstracts extendidos, trabajos en proceso, o casi completados, dependiendo del congreso. Pero nadie que conozco pone estos documentos en el CV.

Más bien, uno lista las conferencias en las que ha participado. Por ende, me entra la duda si lo que en verdad me están preguntando es las conferencias en las que he presentado (a las cuales obviamente he mandado "ponencias"). El hecho de que esa pregunta directa no aparezca refuerza mi impresión. Lo que me hace dudar es que el apartado "ponencias en congresos" se encuentre bajo el tema "Publicaciones".

¿Algúna experiencia con estos conceptos en CV? El contexto es América Latina.

Comment: Una ponencia es una presentación, típicamente en la que lees (en voz alta) algún miniartículo que has preparado, y después los que están te pueden hacer preguntas, criticar o alabar tus ideas, etc.  En inglés equivale a *conference presentation/paper/panel*.  En el mundo académico no solo ponemos los nombres de las conferencias o congresos a que hemos ido, sino también ponemos la ponencia que en ellos dimos (porque simplemente asistir un congreso no vale nada).

Comment: Tu primera interpretación es correcta, pero tu duda sobre la relevancia de ese ítem corresponde más a https://academia.stackexchange.com/ que a este sitio.

Comment: @rsanchez opinó que Academia quedaría mejor para esta pregunta, así que eché un ojo a Academia y encontré una respuesta que muestra cómo incluir ponencias en el CV académico.  Yo no más agregaría que he visto algunos CV con estilo moderno que incluye, como primera página, un resumen de una sola página.  Quizás te gustaría adoptar ese formato, si sientes que tu CV queda muy largo con la inclusión de las ponencias.  ¡Suerte con el trabajo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con el DLE, una ponencia es:

> [**ponencia**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TdkHMGl)
>
> 1. f. Comunicación o propuesta sobre un tema concreto que se somete al examen y resolución de una asamblea.
> 2. f. Encargo dado al ponente.
> 3. f. Función de ponente.
> 4. f. Persona o comisión designada para actuar como ponente.
> 5. f. Informe o dictamen dado por el ponente.

Y según el comentario de guifa:

> Una ponencia es una presentación, típicamente en la que lees (en voz alta) algún miniartículo que has preparado, y después los que están te pueden hacer preguntas, criticar o alabar tus ideas, etc. En inglés equivale a *conference presentation/paper/panel*.

A mi entender, lo que te piden es el **título y/o extracto de las presentaciones y charlas que hayas dado en público en cualesquiera conferencias o eventos a los que hayas asistido**.

Como bien dice guifa, pedir simplemente la lista de conferencias a las que se ha asistido no tendría sentido; solo aquellas a las que hayas asistido como [**ponente**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=TdkzoSM) (|| autor de una ponencia) tienen relevancia real.

La diferencia entre "lista de conferencias en las que has sido ponente" y "lista de ponencias" es sutil: la primera busca conocer los eventos en los que te han aceptado como orador o, por así decirlo, tu grado de notoriedad o fama; la segunda busca conocer los temas de los que has hablado en público, es decir, se centra más en el contenido académico (motivo por el cual lo ubican en la sección de Publicaciones, probablemente).